# Message passing background.js to content.js "Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist."

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am updating my chrome extension from Manifest 2 to Manifest 3. In refactoring my code I wanted to add message passing from the background.js to content.js. When I do that I get the error: "Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist."

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "project-name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "description": "description",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "alarms",
    "declarativeContent",
    "storage",
    "tabs",
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "*://*.myurl.nl/*",
      ],
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "views/popup/popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "images/icon16.png",
      "32": "images/icon32.png",
      "48": "images/icon48.png",
      "128": "images/icon128.png"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
      "16": "images/icon16.png",
      "32": "images/icon32.png",
      "48": "images/icon48.png",
      "128": "images/icon128.png"
  }
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  chrome.storage.local.get('state', (data) => {
    if (data.state === false) {
      chrome.storage.local.set({state: false});
    } else {
      chrome.storage.local.set({state: true});
    }
  });


  const startAlarm = async (name, duration) => {
    chrome.alarms.create(name, { delayInMinutes: duration });
  };

  startAlarm()

  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, () => {
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([
      {
        conditions: [
          new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
            pageUrl: {
              urlContains: 'myurl.'
            }
          })
        ],
        actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowAction()]
      }
    ]);
  });
});


chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener((alarm) => {
  if (alarm.name === 'extension') {
    chrome.storage.local.get(['state'], async (data) => {
      if (data.state !== true) {
        chrome.alarms.clear('extension');
        return;
      }
      const [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true });

      if (tab.id) {
        const res = await chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, { name: 'my-message' });
        console.log(res);
      } else {
        console.error('error');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

content.js

```
console.log('Reached content script file'); // this is reached

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
  console.log('Reached addListener'); // never reached
  if (message.name === 'my-message') {
    handleAction();
  }
  return true;
});

const handleAction = () => {
  ....some code that is never reached
}
```

popup.js

```
console.log('Reached') // never reached
function addButton() {
  ...code that is never reached
}

chrome.storage.local.get('state', (data) => {
  addButton(data.state === true);
});
```

I have read other people online have the same issue. I have tried removing my extension and reloading it, no luck. What may I doing wrong resulting in the above error/why am I unable to send my message and listen to it. Appreciate any insight.

Thanks in advance.
(I have slightly adjusted code for privacy reasons i.e. myurl will be something else)

Comment: 1) You need to [re-inject content scripts](/q/10994324) after reloading/installing the extension or simply reload the tabs. 2) You can't send to a `chrome://` tab or any non-web tab, so you'll have to simply ignore such errors. 3) Are you sure that the active tab is the one that you really need and not the one that matches your content_script's `matches`? 3) Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.